# Check if a scroll bar is visible in .net Framework 1.1 user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, scrollbar, .net-1.1

I am working in .Net framework 1.1 winforms . In usercontrol i want to detect both Horizontal and Vertical Scrollbar Visibility . But In .Net Framework 1.1 there is no property or method to detect the scrollbar visibility.

Comment: .net 1.1?  Can I know the reason behind that?

Comment: Please accept this +1 as a symbol of my deepest condolences that you have to deal with .net 1.1 in 2018.

Comment: @SeM my application requirement is .net 1.1.

Comment: `VScroll` and `HScroll` boolan properties are available since .NET 1.1.

Comment: But why is it 1.1? Mainstream support for .NET Framework 1.1 ended on 14 October 2008. I am just wondering because this could be an XY problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`VScroll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.vscroll(v=vs.71).aspx) and [`HScroll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.hscroll(v=vs.71).aspx) protected boolean properties are available since .NET 1.1.

They allow you to check if the vertical and horizontal scrollbars are visible. They return `true` if the corresponding scrollbar is visible, otherwise return `false`.